# Bluetooth Brecham.Obex 32feet

Tags: c#, .net, 32feet

I have read in the 32feet samples that it can do the folderListings operation, And I'm planning to make more of a File explorer which can do upload and download files,

My question is, can I upload and download a whole folder including its contents using Brecham.obex library? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

32feet.NET includes basic OBEX support which doesn't include folder-listings etc.  However their partner library Brecham.Obex library supports all OBEX features.  See http://alanjmcf.me.uk/thirdparty/Brecham.Obex%20library/

- "The library provides very broad client-side OBEX support, providing not just the ‘Put’ operation that most libraries and applications support, but also the complete set of operations: Connect, Put, Get, SetPath, Delete, and Abort. This is accessed through a session based interface. ... "
- "support for [...] the Folder Listing XML documents as used by the Folder-Browsing service."

Also see the FolderExplorer2 sample shown in that page. It shows folder browsing and download etc.

Get the library download at http://inthehand.com/files/folders/objectexchange/default.aspx

Comment: sorry for the typo, so that means using the brecham.obex i ca achieve the upload and download of folder?