# How to use 32feet.net as raw OBEX library?

Tags: .net, obex, 32feet

If I have a non-Bluetooth device which uses OBEX over a serial port for accessing its file-system, is it possible to use the 32feet.net API to do this, or will I have to look elsewhere?

If I need to look elsewhere, does anyone have any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a constructor to `ObexWebRequest` which takes a `Stream`. That should work for you.

Also Brecham.Obex was created by Andy Hume and is a fully creatured OBEX library. [Bluetooth Brecham.Obex 32feet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339603/bluetooth-brecham-obex-32feet) However it seems to have dropped off the internet. I'll ask Andy to get it back online. It appears in NuGet however https://www.nuget.org/packages/Brecham.Obex/

Comment: Yes, I've looked for the Brecham library but every link I've found is a dead-end!

Comment: Yup, this has caused me to install and use NuGet for the first time and I'm having some success with the Brecham library. Many thanks!

Comment: Grand. Glad to hear it. We're also working on the getting the library back hosted elsewhere.